# Problem with PowerShell in VSCode using Python from Anaconda

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I installed Anaconda and use VSCode as my main editor. I noticed Anaconda defaulted to use PowerShell. I might have messed around with the environment variables and cannot load Python in the terminal. I want to either resolve this or reset everything and clean install.

I also messed around with the following project that involved installing bash and changing some more VSCode settings.

VSCode error:

[image: VSCode Error]

https://github.com/Microsoft/frontend-bootcamp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post screenshots of errors - rather, [edit] your question and copy-paste your error traceback, indented as code. Also, that GitHub link is not needed - it doesn't seem to be relevant to your specific question.

Comment: Is Python and/or Conda in your system Path environment variable?

Comment: Are you typing in `import pandas as pd` or doing something else to get that into the terminal?

Comment: Hi thanks for the input, I made sure conda is in the path environment variable by using conda create --name myenv. I was testing to see if I can run line by line inside the terminal. Even with the path environment  same error shows inside the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have it, I think I just need to launch Python from within the terminal. I was trying to run code directly inside powershell without launching Python.